# Do I need a visa to travel to South Africa with a UK refugee travel document?

Tags: south-africa, refugees

Do I need a visa to travel to South Africa with a UK refugee travel document 1951 Convention travel document.

What documents required and anyone know how to apply visa from the UK?

Comment: You can check visa requirements on the [IATA website](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/) See also https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/Southafrica/uk/english/